# How to make an SQL query in golang with multiple values in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, go

I am trying to perform the following type of query in golang using the sql library:

```
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from someTable where age = ? and hairColor = ?", age,haircolor)
```

But get the following sort of error:

```
    Error occured: sql: expected 1 arguments, got 2
```

How do I perform an SQL select statement in golang where there are multiple values in the WHERE clause?

Comment: which `db` are you using?

Comment: database/sql and mysql.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use a prepared statement so in my example here:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("select * from someTable where age = ? and hairColor = ?")
rows, err := stmt.Query(age,hairColor)
```

This seems obvious in retrospect.  Hopefully this can save somebody a few minutes of hair pulling in the future!

Comment: This doesn't seem obvious, not even in retrospect. Anyways, it should not be necessary to use `Prepare` just to be able to pass more than one argument. Either the original error you got is *not* from the query+args that you've showed, or you're using some broken/unconventional driver.